# sql columns multiplication error

Tags: sql, multiplication

i m trying to execute multiply function in sql but it doesnt compute d values.
d problem is i forgt to create a total row to store the multiplied values n i cant create a new table or add d row..
here is d code i m using n d error it is displayin.
do help.

```
<%
try
{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/invent", "root", "hpdj850c");
   if (!conexion.isClosed())
   {
      Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from store");
      Statement sta = conexion.createStatement();
      ResultSet r = sta.executeQuery("select (rate*quantity) from store");

      out.println("<table class=\"twelve\"><thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Rate</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total</th></tr></thead>");
      while (rs.next() & r.next())
      {

         out.println("<tr>");
         out.println("<td>"+rs.getObject("itemno")+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+rs.getObject("name")+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+rs.getObject("category")+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+rs.getObject("rate")+"</td>");
         out.println("<td>"+rs.getObject("quantity")+"</td>"); 
         out.println("<td>"+r.getStatement() + "</td>");
         out.println("</tr>");

           }
      out.println("</table>");

      conexion.close();
   }
   else
      out.println("fail");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   out.println("Exception " + e);
   e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

total:

com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl@3b46c4

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktracE?

Comment: `r.getStatement()` should be `r.getInt()` or `r.getLong()`. And I recommend to use `getInt()` or `getString()` over `getObject()` for the other ResultSet as well.

Comment: r.getInt() n r.getString both arent working.

Comment: i jus want to execute d query "r"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using two separate query use a single query to achieve this

For eg:

```
select            itemno ,
                  name ,
                  category ,
                  rate ,
                  quantity,
                  rate*quantity as total from Test
```

Comment: can u tell me a java function to updat value in mysql table using java function in session bean.? i dnt cant use sql query.

Comment: like d persist func i m using to store entries in databse.

Comment: public store persist(object odject)                                             {      em.persist(object)      }